# laravel: JSON Field Comparison with Array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

```
laravel-5.7/mysql
```

In my database, I have a json format field like this:

field name: **features**:

```
[
    {"id": 1, "url": null, "name": "A"}, 
    {"id": 2, "url": null, "name": "B"}
]
```

Also in its model,I wrote this

```
  protected $casts = [
    'features' => 'array'
  ];
```

Now I create an array:

```
$features = array();

temp = array();
temp['id'] = 1;
temp['url'] = null;
temp['name'] = A;
$features[] = temp;

temp = array();
temp['id'] = 2;
temp['url'] = null;
temp['name'] = B;
$features[] = temp;
```

How can I compare `$features array`  with `features field`  in the database?

ّI checked these:

```
$fff = \App\Cart::whereFeatures($features)->get()->first();
```

or

```
$fff = \App\Cart::whereFeatures(json_encode($features))->get()->first();
```

or

```
$fff = \App\Cart::whereFeatures(json_encode($features,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE))->get()->first();
```

Comment: I think before you call `get()` you are working with query builder, so it will maybe be a string comparison with what is in the database column.

Answer (score 7):

Use a raw expression to cast the comparison value:

```
$fff = \App\Cart::whereRaw('features = cast(? as json)', json_encode($features))->get();
```

Comment: This really helped me out. and i didn't knew that we can pass a second argument else we have to write like this and it would cause problems with single quotes i guess.

`whereRaw("options = CAST('".json_encode($options)."') as JSON)")`